# Restoring Contacts groups from Time Machine

Tags: backup, time-machine, contacts

For reasons unknown, everything just completely vanished from my Contacts (including contacts and all of my groups).  Note, these are all Contacts that were stored *on my Mac* -- I don't use iCloud and they are not synced anywhere else.

No problem -- I have a Time Machine backup, so I enter TM, scroll back in time to yesterday, and there they are.  I select all and restore all of my contacts.  Back in the present, all of my individual contacts are there.  *But none of the groups are.*

I've just spent several hours fruitlessly trying to figure out how to restore my groups.  One thing that has *not* worked is copying the entire Application Support > AddressBook folder from my Time Machine to my user library:  when I try this, and then restart Contacts, the entire list is empty again.  (I don't understand this behavior at all, by the way.)

> Where does Contacts store my group metadata?  How can I restore it from a Time Machine backup?

Answer (score 1):

Over the last couple of weeks, I’ve been dealing with trying to selectively restore certain data types from TM. Upon disabling the iCloud on a few devices, I lost contacts, calendar, reminders and notes.

I worked with a senior Apple advisor to restore contacts and calendars from TM. (We were unable to get reminders and notes - argh.) I experienced what you have, some restore attempts did not bring back groups. I use groups heavily and so was very determined to find a solution that brought back both contacts and groups.

When I saw your post yesterday, I contacted the Apple advisor to confirm the steps we took to restore contacts, that included groups. He says that it was going to ~Library/Application Support/Address Book, and restoring that entire folder was the solution. I can’t remember for sure (we were trying lots of different things), but he says that was the one that worked. I have to assume he is correct.

In your message, you indicate that this is the route you tried without success. Keep trying...I want to let you know there is a solution, I was able to do so.

C.

Answer (score 0):

In Contacts, look at the View menu; you can hide groups, or show groups.

The data (at least, in El Capitan, 10.11.6) is in

"/Users/your_name_here/Library/Application Support/AddressBook"

When I delete a group, it changes the files
"Metadata" and "AddressBook-v22.abcddb-wal"

Comment: You don't seem to have understood the question. The groups have been DELETED. And as I already said that restoring the entire Application/AddressBook directory didn't help, just telling me that they're somewhere in that folder is obviously not helpful.

Comment: What is the evidence of deletion?   Could it be disappearance?  Change in the View menu explains disappearance.

Comment: When you hide groups the sidebar disappears.  In this case the sidebar  is present, but empty:  it says "All Contacts" and there is nothing below it.

Comment: Two files change when I delete a group (see edited answer above)